# Swift DispatchQueue: Serial or parallel

Tags: swift, multithreading, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

In my app, I have to decompress multiple files in the background, all in the same time. Which code yields a parallel execution of the *compressedFiles* array on multiple threads:

```
for file in compressedFiles {
  DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
    let work = DispatchGroup()
    work.enter()
    file.decompress()
    work.leave()
  }
}
```

or:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
  for file in compressedFiles {
    let work = DispatchGroup()
    work.enter()
    file.decompress()
    work.leave()
  }
}
```

In addition, how to take advantage of the DispatchGroup class if I want to be notified once one of the files decompression process is finished? Where to put wait() and notify()?

Thanks.

Comment: As an aside, I might advise `.userInitiated` or `.utility` QoS, not `.userInteractive`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second example will run them sequentially. It is doing a single dispatch, running them one after another. Your first example will run them in parallel, dispatching each to a different worker thread. Unfortunately, though, neither is using the dispatch group correctly.

Regarding the dispatch group, you should define it before your loop and `enter` before you call `async`. But the manual calling of `enter` and `leave` is only needed if you're calling an asynchronous process from within the `async` call. But given that `decompress` is likely a synchronous process, you can just supply the group to `async`, and it will take care of everything for you:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

for file in compressedFiles {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async(group: group) {
        file.decompress()
    }
}

group.notify(queue: .main) {
    // all done
}
```

---

But rather than worrying about the dispatch group logic, there is a deeper problem in the parallel example. Specifically, it suffers from thread explosion, where it can exceed the number of available cores on your CPU. Worse, if you had a lot of files to decompress, you can even exceed the limited number of worker threads that GCD has in its pool. And when that happens, it can prevent anything else from running on GCD for that QoS. Instead, you want to run it in parallel, but you want to constrain it to a reasonable degree of concurrency, while still enjoying parallelism, to avoid exhausting resources for other tasks.

If you want it to run in parallel, but also avoid thread explosion, one would often reach for [`concurrentPerform`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2016088-concurrentperform). That offers maximum parallelism supported by the CPU, but preventing problems that can result from thread explosion:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: compressedFiles.count) { index in
        compressedFiles[index].decompress()
    }
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // all done
    }
}
```

That will constrain the parallelism to the maximum permitted by the cores on your device. It also eliminates the need for the dispatch group.

---

Alternatively, if you want to enjoy parallelism, but with a lower degree of concurrency (e.g. to leave some cores available for other tasks, to minimize peak memory usage, etc.), you might use use operation queues and `maxConcurrentOperationCount`:

```
let queue = OperationQueue()
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 4  // a max of 4 decompress tasks at a time

let completion = BlockOperation {
    // all done
}

for file in compressedFiles {
    let operation = BlockOperation {
        file.decompress()
    }
    completion.addDependency(operation)
    queue.addOperation(operation)
}

OperationQueue.main.addOperation(completion)
```

---

Or at matt points out, in iOS 13 (or macOS 10.15) and later, you can do:

```
let queue = OperationQueue()
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 4

for file in compressedFiles {
    queue.addOperation {
        file.decompress()
    }
}

queue.addBarrierBlock {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // all done
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what "new" was supposed to mean. I was just saying it's cool now that it exists.

Answer (score 0):

The dispatch group needs to be outside the loop, and each `enter` needs to be inside the loop but outside the thread containing the `leave`. But then the *entire* code also needs to be in its own dispatch queue, since you cannot block (wait) on the main queue.

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label:"myqueue")
queue.async {
    let work = DispatchGroup()
    for file in compressedFiles {
        work.enter()
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
            file.decompress()
            work.leave()
        }
    }
    work.notify... // get on main thread here?
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the initiation of the DispatchGroup be inside the for loop to create multiple threads in parallel, i.e. one thread for each file? As well as for the notify()?

Comment: Yes, my answer was purely based on the architecture of the OP’s original code (“which code”) and expressed goal (“parallel execution of the compressedFiles array on multiple threads”). The OP did not ask if that was a good idea.